# Why do Scanner.nextDouble() and System.out.println behave differently regarding locale?

Tags: java, locale

I teach Java to beginning programmers and many of my Dutch students get confused the first time they have to use Scanner to input floating point values.

The default behavior of nextDouble() is to consult the locale setting of the computer. When the setting is Dutch, this means that a decimal comma has to be used.

On the other hand, System.out.println does not seem to consider the locale and uses a decimal point.

Consider for example the following output (user input in bold):

> Give a number below 10.0
>
> **10,5**
>
> Sorry, 10.5 is not below 10.0

(When one would type 10.5, an InputMismatchException will be thrown.) The output above is produced by the following fragment

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    double limit = 10.0;
    System.out.println( "Give a number below "+limit );
    double x = scanner.nextDouble();
    if (x >= limit ) {
        System.out.println( "Sorry, "+x+" is not below "+limit );
    }
```

Is this an inconsistency in the library or do I use it in the wrong way?

Comment: It's not `println`, it's `String` concatenation.

Comment: So ultimately, it comes down to the specifications for [Double.toString(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29), which is not locale sensitive.  For locale sensitive formatting, use a `Formatter`.

Comment: Use `System.out.printf("Sorry, %1$f is not below %2$f", x, limit)` to consistently use the locale.

Answer (score 2):

The argument provided to this invocation

```
System.out.println( "Sorry, "+x+" is not below "+limit );
```

is a `String` that is the result of concatenating some `String` literals and some `double` values.

[The JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then [string
>   conversion (§5.1.11)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time.

and then

> A value `x` of primitive type `T` is first converted to a reference value
>   as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance
>   creation expression (§15.9):
>
> - If `T` is `double`, then use `new Double(x)`.

It then goes on to say

> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"`
>   is used instead.

The javadoc of [`Double#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString--) explains the format

> Returns a string representation of this `Double` object. The primitive
>   `double` value represented by this object is converted to a string
>   exactly as if by the method `toString` of one argument.

which is the overloaded [`toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) method

> Returns a string representation of the double argument. All characters
>   mentioned below are ASCII characters.
>
> - If the argument is `NaN`, the result is the string `"NaN"`.
> - Otherwise, the result is a string that represents the sign and magnitude (absolute value) of the argument. If the sign is negative,
>     the first character of the result is `'-' ('\u002D')`; if the sign is
>     positive, no sign character appears in the result. As for the
>     magnitude m:
>
>   - If `m` is infinity, it is represented by the characters `"Infinity"`; thus, positive infinity produces the result `"Infinity"` and
>       negative infinity produces the result `"-Infinity"`.
>   - If `m` is zero, it is represented by the characters `"0.0"`; thus, negative zero produces the result `"-0.0"` and positive zero produces
>       the result "0.0".
>   - If `m` is greater than or equal to `10^-3` but less than `10^7`, then it is represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no
>       leading zeroes, followed by `'.' ('\u002E')`, followed by one or more
>       decimal digits representing the fractional part of `m`.
>   - If m is less than `10^-3` or greater than or equal to `10^7`, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let
>       n be the unique integer such that `10^n ≤ m < 10n+1`; then let a be the
>       mathematically exact quotient of m and `10^n` so that `1 ≤ a < 10`. The
>       magnitude is then represented as the integer part of `a`, as a single
>       decimal digit, followed by `'.' ('\u002E')`, followed by decimal digits
>       representing the fractional part of `a`, followed by the letter `'E'`
>       `('\u0045')`, followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as
>       produced by the method `Integer.toString(int)`.
>
> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of `m` or `a`?
>   There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to
>   uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type
>   double. That is, suppose that `x` is the exact mathematical value
>   represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for
>   a finite nonzero argument `d`. Then `d` must be the `double` value nearest
>   to `x`; or if two `double` values are equally close to `x`, then `d` must be
>   one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of `d` must
>   be `0`.
>
> **To create localized string representations of a floating-point value,
>   use subclasses of `NumberFormat`.**

which describes how to properly format a `double`.

Alternatively, use `printf` and provide the appropriate format pattern for floating point values.

Answer (score 2):

- String concatenation, String.format, printf, Double.toString, Double.valueOf all use the decimal *point* without thousand separator, compatible to java source code. This is fortunately a **basic non-localized representation**, useful **for textual transport of data**.
- Scanner, NumberFormat, MessageFormat involve **localization**, sometimes a bit awkward. They are for high-level code, **for user interaction**. With the thousand separator too.

One has to make a choice to one. Using localized numbers at the minimum is a good exercise. Or when being lazy one might use `Double.parseDouble` instead of `Scanner` or:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Another format/value issue is the usage of double which is an approximation, and has no precision, as the fixed point BigDecimal. Doubles should be used for fast calculations, and BigDecimal for financial precision.

```
new BigDecimal("0.20") // Precision of 2, no loss.
0.20 // Not exactly 0.20, no precision on printing
```